# Exporting DXF contour lines in QGIS. Units Problem

Tags: qgis

I am trying to export the contour lines of a topography from QGIS to DXF AutoCAD to generate a 3d model of it. The data comes from a source that has the elevation in FT. It matches with my coordinates system in plan but when I export it the Z Height remains in ft. How can I change that in QGIS so I get my model in meters?

---

Still having the same issue. Once I am in Rhino or Cad, elevation data is at scale but then the distances horizontally do not match at all (are scaled more than 10.000 times).
Sorry to be such a pill... The file I am using to be more specific is this one https://geohub.lacity.org/datasets/contour-lines-2006.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to create a new field, it will contain the elevation converted to meters.  Then use the processing tool, Set Z value (under Vector geometry).  Change the Z Value to be data defined and set it to the new field you created with meters.  Then click run.

[image: set z value]

Go to the Project menu to export to DXF (Project -> Import/Export -> Export Project to DXF).  Put a name in the save as box and make sure to only export the layer you added the Z value.  Please note that AutoCAD does not handle WGS 84 (latitude and longitude) coordinate system very well.
[image: dxf export]

Open the DXF file in AutoCAD and those lines should have the elevation.

[image: autocad 3d]

Comment: This was really helpful altough I am still having an issue. When I exported the file into AutoCAD and open it, the Z height is correct altough X and Y coordinates shrinked (In plan it has the correct XY ratio but it is way smaller in scale). Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: How much smaller is it?  Do you have an approximate scale?  Make sure you exported the correct coordinate system.

Comment: In my images you will see EPSG:2272, make sure you change this to use the same coordinate system you are using for your data.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, The problem was that I was using WGS 84 and seems it is a CRS that Autocad does not support so It worked when I exported it using NAD83 / UTM 10 N